# В PyQt5 программу открыть на 4 дисплее

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Помогите разобраться как открыть программу на 4ом экране? Нашла этот код, однако не могу понять "widget =  # define your widget" эту строку. Каким образом я должна сделать define моего виджета? Просто написать название файла  которую нужно открыть на 4 экране? или путь файла указать? (оба варианта не работают) Заранее спасибо!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDesktopWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget =  # define your widget
display_monitor = 4 # the number of the monitor you want to display your widget

monitor = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(display_monitor)
widget.move(monitor.left(), monitor.top())
widget.showFullScreen()
```

Comment: Ну вместо `# define your widget` поместить ваш виджет, типа `widget = QWidget()`

Comment: Спасибо! А возможно ли такие настройки для окна задавать не в самом  коде питон, а конфиг файлом отдельно? Чтобы потом можно было ее поменять быстро

Comment: Хотите в конфиге хранить значение `display_monitor`?

Comment: да, чтобы быстро менять экраны при необходимости

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `# define your widget` укажите любой виджет, например:

```
widget = QWidget()
```

Настройки можно хранить в любом формате, который вам будет удобным. Приведу пример с `json`.

Создаете файл `config.json` с таким содержимым:

```
{
    "display_monitor": 4
}
```

И меняете код так:

```
import json
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QWidget()

config = json.load(open('config.json'))
display_monitor = config['display_monitor']

monitor = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(display_monitor)
widget.move(monitor.left(), monitor.top())
widget.showFullScreen()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Благодарю тебя, добрый человек! Все сработало!

Comment: @g_0008, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)